# Can't Find Grid Panel on Sencha Architect

Tags: sencha-architect

I started to use Sencha Architect and I'm following the [Car Listing tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/first_desktop_app)

I'm using the Sencha Architect 2.2.1 and on the tutorial it say to add a grid panel founded on ToolBox label, but on my toolbox don't have any Grid Panel.

It was renamed on this version ?

Here a print screen that i'm searching for grid on the panel
[image]

Here a link for big screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxcal.png

Comment: Have you tried searching for just `grid`

Comment: I posted a picture, but its to small, i'm uploading a picture to a server, and yes cclerville, i searched on toolbox

Comment: I posted a link for the big screen image, someone know why i cant find the grid ?

Comment: Wow thats strange... See if anyone if experiencing this on the sencha forums as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your screenshot it seems that's a Sencha Touch project, and the grid widget is available only in ExtJs not in Sencha Touch.
If you need a grid in Sencha Touch there is a third party extension found here : [Bryntum UberGrid](http://www.bryntum.com/products/ubergrid/)

Regards,
Danny